# wkhtmltopdf - adding a sidebar that follows a span of varying text

Tags: javascript, html, css, wkhtmltopdf

I'm attempting to add a sidebar to the left edge of an outputted PDF whenever any text is within a span with class `sidebar`. The main problem I'm running into is that when text spans run multiple lines, calculating the span's height or coordinates in JS within wkhtmltopdf returns values that appear incorrect, so I don't have proper values to size or position a generated sidebar element. I'm open to any ideas that may make this work.

Some of the things I've tried:

- Creating the sidebar as a `:before` pseudo element within the span (sample below). If I set the span to `position: relative` and `:before` to `position: absolute; height: 100%; left: 0`, it does produce a bar that matches the span height but it's rendered inside the span and I can't get a correct offset left value to reposition the bar. Within wkhtmltopdf, `getBoundingClientRect().left` and `offset().left` reads as `8` for the :before element (due to page margin?) and `0` for its parent span.
- Creating the sidebar as a `:before` pseudo element, but without setting its parent to `position: relative`. In this case, the bar does show on the left edge of the PDF, but I can't get a correct span height to apply to the sidebar. A 3 line span somehow returns a height of over a thousand pixels when I get `offsetHeight`. Same result when I subtract `getBoundingClientRect().top` from `getBoundingClientRect().bottom`. Block elements have the same behavior. Perhaps wkhtmltopdf boxes run to the bottom of the page.
- Creating the sidebar as a `:before` pseudo element, with `position: absolute` to the left edge of the page, then sizing it by adding line breaks (via its `content` style) to match a count of soft breaks in the span using `getClientRects()`. Within wkhtmltopdf, getClientRects().length is giving me `63` for a 3 line span.
- Appending and prepending two divs when the span is detected, then using canvas to draw a line between them. For this idea, I needed coordinates for the two divs and got stopped when the second div somehow returned a negative number for `offset().top`.
- For the JS, I did try both having it embedded, and running it from the command line with `--run-script`. Same results.

---

```
<style>
  .sidebar { position: relative; background-color: yellow; }
  .sidebar::before { position: absolute; content: ''; border-left: 2px #000 solid; left: 0; height: 100%; }
</style>

<body>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. <span class="sidebar">Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.</span> Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</body>
```

---

[Here's a mock-up of my target. The sidebar on the left here matches the height of the yellow selected text.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQkpn.png)

Comment: Is it safe to assume that a test html file only contains the provided code?  Also, can you provide the wkthmltopdf command you run so that we're on the same page.  Also, it would be nice if you can do a rough image mockup of the intended end result.  Would love to tackle this challenge.

Comment: Yes, the provided code came out of my test file, minus all the commented-out JS from my various failed attempts. The command I'm using is: wkhtmltopdf --debug-javascript test.html test.pdf. I've added a rough comp of the target. Thanks!

Comment: I assume you want to stick with css and not javascript, correct?

Comment: Preferably, but for starters, I'm looking for any working solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
</<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        body {
            height: 842px;
            width: 595px;
        }

        .sidebar {
            background-color: yellow;
        }

        .sidebar::before {
            position: fixed;
            content: '';
            border-left: 2px #000 solid;
            left: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
    <span class="sidebar">Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.
    </span> Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?

    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
            var span = document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar')[0];
            document.styleSheets[0].addRule('.sidebar::before', 'height: ' + span.offsetHeight + 'px;');
        });
    </script>
</body>


</html>
```

**Note: I had to had to add the body style of height and width for wkhtmltopdf javascript to show correct span.offsetHeight.  Without that, the height was too big.**

Testing in Chrome, I didn't need the body style, but wkhtmltopdf, it did.

I just set it to some width/height pixels, but you can set it to the correct pixels taking into considerations the margins.

Comment: I've played with this a little and here are some findings so far: 1) The `fixed` sidebar doesn't work in Chrome when the page scrolls, but (fortunately/unfortunately) does stay fixed with its text in the PDF. 2) This doesn't work with multiple sidebars (which I didn't state as an earlier requirement), but that can be worked out based on what you've provided. 3) Turns out, the key to getting an accurate `offsetHeight` was to declare a `width` on the body. That's what I really needed. Thanks, you're a life saver!

Comment: Yeah, that stump me too.  Took a while to get the correct height in wkhtmltopdf.